# Python - Convert string with special characters to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, special-characters

I run the following code:

```
x=b"a\bcde"
print(x)
```

Then I have `b'a\x08cde'` as the value of `x`. But I want `b'a\bcde'` instead of `b'a\x08cde'` for x. I tried to use `x ="a\bcde".encode("utf-8")` instead, but still have the same result. What should I do?

Many thanks!

Comment: I've tried a bit of testing and the '\' makes the b a character with unicode value 8

Comment: @PietroMarsella Yes, `\b` is the escape sequence for the backspace character. You may be familiar with `\t` (TAB) and `\r\n` (CARRIAGE RETURN and NEW LINE). This is from the time where computers had no monitors and we used a [Teleprinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) machine as a terminal (think of it as a typewriter that could send what you typed to a remote typewriter through a telephone line).

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm (note the double backslash):

```
x = b"a\\bcde"
print(x)
```

And from now on just remember to double your backslashes when you use them in the strings.

Comment: I also tried this (tried on both my computer and Colab notebook) before I wrote this post... But I can't got `b'a\bcde'`... what I got is `b'a\\bcde'`.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same byte sequence. The `"\b"` is the backspace character, `08` in hexadecimal:

```
>> b"a\bcde" == b'a\x08cde'
True
```

If you want a literal backslash instead of the backspace character you have to escape the backslash or use a raw string.

```
>> b"a\\bcde"
b'a\\bcde'

>> br"a\bcde"
b'a\\bcde'
```

Last, don't be fooled by the representation also using a double backslash, the value has a single backslash when printed or used otherwise.

```
>> print(br"a\bcde".decode('ascii'))
a\bcde
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash `\` character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

```
example:

\\  Backslash (\)    
\'  Single quote (')     
\"  Double quote (")
```

You have two options:

1. Escaping the backslash `x = b'a\\bcde'`
2. Declare the string as raw `x = r'a\bcde'`